# Trying to create a python dictionary for 4x4 board coordinates

Tags: python, dictionary

I want the desired output as-

`coord = 
{0: (0, 0), 1: (0, 1), 2: (0, 2), 3: (0, 3),
4: (1, 0), 5: (1, 1), 6: (1, 2),
7: (1, 3),8: (2, 0), 9: (2, 1), 10: (2, 2),
11: (2, 3),12: (3, 0), 13: (3, 1), 14: (3, 2), 15: (3, 3)}`

using

```
coord = {}

for i in range(0,16):

    if i < 4:
        for j in range (0,4):
            coord[i] = (0,j)
    elif   i > 3 and i <8:
        for j in range (0,4):
            coord[i] = (1,j)
    elif i > 7 and i < 12:
        for j in range (0,4):
            coord[i] = (1,j)
    elif i > 11 and i < 16:
        for j in range (0,4):
            coord[i] = (1,j)
print (coord)
```

getting the output as
`{0: (0, 3), 1: (0, 3), 2: (0, 3), 3: (0, 3), 4: (1, 3), 5: (1, 3), 6: (1, 3), 7: (1, 3), 8: (1, 3), 9: (1, 3), 10: (1, 3), 11: (1, 3), 12: (1, 3), 13: (1, 3), 14: (1, 3), 15: (1, 3)}`

not able to build the logic to get desired output.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want a dictionary here? A `dict` who's keys are all increasing integers starting at 0 is basically an inefficient `list`, unless you would like some other property of `dict` objects?

Comment: In all four cases you have `coord[i] = (0, j)` or `coord[i] = (1, j)`. How do you expect the first item in each entry to be anything but 0 or 1?

Comment: I know its wrong logic but I am new to python so trying to learn by experimenting.

Comment: oh...my bad it should be 2 and 3 for the last two elif. But then also the output is wrong.

Comment: well, there is one loop solution too, might be even faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straightforward way is using the nested for loop.

```
k = 0
d = {}
for i in range(4):
     for j in range(4):
         d[k] = (i, j)
         k += 1
```

or, if you prefer oneliners, double comprehension

```
 dict( enumerate ( [ (i, j) for i in range(4) for j in range(4)] ))
```

To have one simple for loop or comprehension we can use integer arithmetic operators // (integer division) and % remainder

```
 { k : (k // 4, k % 4) for k in range(16) }
```

This probably more elegant and fast

Answer (score 0):

We can enumerate a [*Cartesian product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of integers with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
import itertools as it


{i: x for i, x in enumerate(it.product(range(3+1), repeat=2))}
# {0: (0, 0),
#  1: (0, 1),
#  2: (0, 2),
#  3: (0, 3),
#  ...
#  15: (3, 3)}
```